# Power BI Export Data to Excel

Tags: powerbi

I have a daily dataset I get every day from our IT.

- I check if the dates in that dataset are already present in the historical dataset.
- If so I remove them by creating an anti-join in power BI which returns the hist table without any of the records in the daily file
- I then append the daily results to the table.

I would then like to export the results back to the original historical excel file. Is something like this possible in Power BI. I have tried using both R and Python for this within powerBI but get

> Formula.Firewall: Query 'hist_data' (step 'Run R script') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.

Comment: I am not sure this is the right place for your question. Anyway, if your transformation is in PowerQuery, there is also PowerQuery in Excel. Probably the easiest would be to do the “update” of your historical data table via Python or R separately. There is also the option to export data from the visuals as CSV. In principle, PowerBI was not designed to write back to the sources.

Comment: Check out the live connection feature. This will create a table in Excel connected to your data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-analyze-in-excel#:~:text=Desktop%20app.-,Export%20to%20Excel%20with%20live%20connection,-While%20viewing%20a

Comment: Formula firewall is usually a data privacy issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/desktop-privacy-levels